Problem with Tikz figures. Errors when I try to use vectors
I am having a series of problems with Tikz figures that I am creating.
I have the following files:

main.tex: the document type is defined and the necessary files are imported.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside]{report}
\input{./Tex_Files/packages.tex}
\begin{document}
\input{./Tex_Files/01.tex}
\end{document}


packages.tex: I write the packages that I am going to use and I import them to the main. The packages that I am using to create the tikz figures are:


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\decimalpoint
\renewcommand{\spanishtablename}{Tabla}
\addto\extrasenglish{
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes, positioning}


Figures_Tikz.tex: I write the code to create Tikz figures. In the attached code (Elipse.tex) you can see an example with which I am having problems. The problem comes when I try to draw vectors, lines with arrows or anything other than a straight line.


\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{6} 
\def\b{4} 
\def\e{0.8} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)} 
\draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (\a cm and \b cm);
\draw[dashed] (-\a,0) -- (\a,0);
\draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (\a,-2) node[midway, above] {$a$};
\draw[dashed] (\a,0) -- (\a,-2);
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (0,\b) ;
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (0,-\b);
\filldraw[black] (\f,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {$F$};
\filldraw[black] (\a,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] 
{Pericentro};
\filldraw[black] (\f,0) circle (2pt) node[above];
\draw[->](\f,0)--(\f + \e, 0) node[midway, above] {$\vec{e}$};
\draw[<->] (0,-1) -- (\f,-1) node[midway, above] {$ae$};
\end{tikzpicture}

For example in the line 13 get the following error:
Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@addpath was complete.
Missing \endcsname inserted.
Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@splitter was complete.
Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@splitter was complete.
Missing \endcsname inserted.
Missing \endcsname inserted.
Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg> was complete.
Missing \endcsname inserted.
Paragraph ended before \pgfkeys@addpath was complete.
Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.
Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg> was complete


01.tex: I write the code of the different chapters. In order to insert the Tikz Figure as an imagen, I write the following:


\chapter{} \label{ch:chapter_01}
\section{}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{./Figures_Tikz/Elipse.tex}
\caption{Semieje mayor y excentricidad de una órbita.}
\label{fig:elipse}
\end{figure}

The thing is that if I enter it in another totally new document with the following aspect I have no problem:
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{6}
\def\b{4}
\def\e{0.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\f} {sqrt(\a^2 - \b^2)}
\draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (\a cm and \b cm);
\draw[dashed] (-\a, 0)
(\a, 0);
\draw[dashed] (\a,0)
\draw[->] (0,-2) (\a,-2) node[midway, above] {$a$};
(\a,-2);
\draw[dashed] (0,0)
(0,\b);
\draw[dashed] (0,0)
(0,-\b);
\filldraw [black] (\f,0) circle (2pt);
\filldraw [black] (\a,0) circle (2pt) node [anchor=west] {$\text{Pericentro}$};
\draw[->] (\f, 0)--(\f 0.8, 0) node [midway, above] {$\vec{e}$}; \draw[->] (0,-1) (\f,-1) node[midway, above] {Sae$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Elipse con pericentro y excentricidad. }
\label{fig:elipse}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

In this code I have no errors and the ellipse is drawn well. I show you the comparison:

In short, in my file that I have better organized importing files does not work and in the other one it does. How can I fix it?
If you need more information do not hesitate to contact me.
Thank you very much for your time

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a full minimal working example which reproduces the issue, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. And post it as text, not screenshot of code. Nobody wants to type everything from scratch.

We need something we can copy-paste and compile to reproduce the error you show. Right now, your example is very far from minimal. Moreover, nobody can compile it but you because we don't have the files it depends on. So only you can reproduce the problem. In order to help you effectively, we must be able to do the same. That said, I'd guess this is language related. Since you don't show any language setup, I assume the problem lies in code you've not shared.

Off-topic: Note that both \a and \b are defined by LaTeX. You are only overwriting those definitions locally (inside the tikzpicture), but you must take care you are not clobbering anything you need.

You can try loading the TikZ babel library. (I can't figure out if this is now obsolete, necessary in fewer cases or still necessary, but you can always remove it if it doesn't help.)

Thanks everyone, I have changed the code to make it reproducible. It looks like adding the Tikz babel library fixed the problem.
